# Terminal prompts have a mysterious [I] in it

Tags: prompt, fish

I have been using fish shell for a while, but only recently got into playing around with the oh-my-fish framework and theming the prompt.

I cannot figure out what this [I] character means! In most themes I install it comes at the very beginning of the prompt, but depending it can be elsewhere.

In my fish_prompt.fish file I see this function:

```
function fish_prompt -d 'Write out the left prompt of the dangerous theme'
  set -g last_status $status
  echo -n -s (__dangerous_prompt_bindmode) (__dangerous_prompt_git_branch) (__dangerous_prompt_left_symbols) ' '
end
```

I cannot figure out what is causing the [I]. I am using the dangerous theme if that matters (however, I see the [I] in all of the themes)

I would love if someone can shed some light on this for me! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `[I]` signifies "Vi Insert Mode" when the shell is in Vi command line editing mode.

This changes to `[N]` when you press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to enter "Vi Normal Mode" (also sometimes referred to as "Vi Command Mode").

The solution (to remove the `[I]`) is to use

```
function fish_mode_prompt
end
```

in your `fish` configuration file.

Comment: Oh wow. That explains it. I don't use Vi. Should it be showing even when I am not running vi?

Comment: @JordanRhea The command line editor, what you use to change things on the command line, is in "vi-mode".  This does not mean that you are using the Vi editor.

Comment: @JordanRhea See updated answer.

Comment: Perfect. One last thing to add. You can run the function on the command line and then save it with `funcsave fish_mode_prompt`